# Trying to implement Twig and Assetic without Symfony2 into my project

Tags: php, twig, assetic

Im using the Twig library in my projects for a long time now and just recently heard of Assetic. Im currently trying to implement this library into my projects and have a very hard time doing so.

**What I want**
I just want to add css/js resources inside my twig templates and have them dumped when needed to static files so the browser can find them.

I cant find any good documentation or tutorial that shows ALL needed code or at least explain why i have to do what. Maybe someone can help?

Here are the relevant parts of what I have (not showing all my frameworking stuff):

**The PHP part**

```
// Init Twig
$TwigLoader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($templatesPath]);
$Twig = new Twig_Environment($TwigLoader, $environment);

// Init Assetic
$FilterManager = new FilterManager();
$AssetFactory = new AssetFactory($assetsPath);
$AssetFactory->setAssetManager($AssetManager);
$AssetFactory->setFilterManager($FilterManager);
$AssetFactory->setDebug(DEBUG);

// Enable Assetic extension in Twig
$Twig->addExtension(new AsseticExtension($AssetFactory));

// Render a page
$Template = $this->Twig->loadTemplate($template);
$Output = $Template->render($Data);

// Dump compiled assets - THIS IS MOST PROBABLY COMPLETELY WRONG???
$AssetManager = new LazyAssetManager($AssetFactory);
$AssetManager->setLoader('twig', new TwigFormulaLoader($Twig));
$resource = new TwigResource($Twig->getLoader(), $template);
$AssetManager->addResource($resource, 'twig');

$writer = new AssetWriter('../public/assets');
$writer->writeManagerAssets($AssetManager);
```

**The Twig part**

I have a "index.html.twig" template (above used in my $template variable than includes a "head.html.twig" file. These are the contents of that file:

```
{% stylesheets 'styles/base.css' output='css/all.css' %}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

**The result**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/all_base_1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">Welcome</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The "css/all_base_1.css" is nowhere to be found though and I dont get any PHP errors along the way.

Comment: Found out, when I use `head.html.twig` instead of it's parent `index.html.twig` in the "// Dump compiled assets" part, it at least dumps the css file to disc. It still doesnt have the name generated by the twig-assetic extension though. And I doubt this is the intended way...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working, but I still think this solution is rather strange:

I put all uncompiled assets into public accessible folders so they can be used if the `$AssetFactory` is set to DEBUG.

If I iterate over all Templates in my `// Dump compiled assets` part and specify and `output` filename in my twig templates, it will generate all files and link to them.

This solution feels strange as I add all asset files during template rendering, only to have assetic to iterate over all templates again to dump the static versions. So Im basically adding my assets twice and parsing loads of templates for no reason. Is this upposed to work like this?

The Assetic documentation still is rather useless on all of this, sadly...